# How to sequence a number in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have following input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
<Worker>
    <id>1234</id>
    <loc>New York</loc>
    <Days>1</Days>
    <StartDate>2019-01-26</StartDate>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    <id>2345</id>
    <loc>Boston</loc>
    <Batch>A</Batch>
    <Days>3</Days>
    <Units>2</Units>
    <StartDate>2019-02-01</StartDate>
</Worker>
</Workers>
```

My code looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result- 
prefixes="#all">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Worker[Batch]">
 <xsl:variable name="currElem" select="."/>
 <xsl:for-each select="1 to Days">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$currElem" mode="replicate">
    <xsl:with-param name="dayNo" select="."/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="1 to Units">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$currElem" mode="replicate">
    <xsl:with-param name="dayNo" select="."/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Worker" mode="replicate">
<xsl:param name="dayNo"/>
<Worker>
  <xsl:sequence select="id, loc"/>
  <RecordNumber><xsl:value-of select="$dayNo"/></RecordNumber>
  <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
  <StartDate>
    <xsl:value-of select="xs:date(StartDate) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D') * 
($dayNo - 1)"/>
  </StartDate>
</Worker>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
<Worker>
    <id>1234</id>
    <loc>New York</loc>
    <Days>1</Days>
    <StartDate>2019-01-26</StartDate>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    <id>2345</id>
    <loc>Boston</loc>
    <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
    <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
    <StartDate>2019-02-01</StartDate>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    <id>2345</id>
    <loc>Boston</loc>
    <RecordNumber>2</RecordNumber>
    <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
    <StartDate>2019-02-02</StartDate>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    <id>2345</id>
    <loc>Boston</loc>
    <RecordNumber>3</RecordNumber>
    <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
    <StartDate>2019-02-03</StartDate>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    <id>2345</id>
    <loc>Boston</loc>
    <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
    <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
    <StartDate>2019-02-01</StartDate>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    <id>2345</id>
    <loc>Boston</loc>
    <RecordNumber>2</RecordNumber>
    <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
    <StartDate>2019-02-02</StartDate>
</Worker>
 </Workers>
```

I need `<RecordNumber></RecordNumber>` to display the sequenced numbers. Currently it's showing 1, 2, 3 and 1, 2.

Instead of this, i need 1, 2, 3, 4,5 .

Currently my XSLT code has two `<for-each>` loops being executed based on the values of `<Days>` and `<Units>`( pls. refer second `<Worker>` node in my sample input xml). i think this is why i am getting 1,2,3 and 1,2 in `<RecordNumber>`

I tried using position `position()`and declaring it as variable and use it in my template, which seems not working.

I also tried another for-each loop to execute `position()` which also seems to be not working

Expected Output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
<Worker>
    <id>1234</id>
    <loc>New York</loc>
    <Days>1</Days>
    <StartDate>2019-01-26</StartDate>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    <id>2345</id>
    <loc>Boston</loc>
    <RecordNumber>1</RecordNumber>
    <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
    <StartDate>2019-02-01</StartDate>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    <id>2345</id>
    <loc>Boston</loc>
    <RecordNumber>2</RecordNumber>
    <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
    <StartDate>2019-02-02</StartDate>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    <id>2345</id>
    <loc>Boston</loc>
    <RecordNumber>3</RecordNumber>
    <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
    <StartDate>2019-02-03</StartDate>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    <id>2345</id>
    <loc>Boston</loc>
    <RecordNumber>4</RecordNumber>
    <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
    <StartDate>2019-02-01</StartDate>
</Worker>
<Worker>
    <id>2345</id>
    <loc>Boston</loc>
    <RecordNumber>5</RecordNumber>
    <WorkerDays>1</WorkerDays>
    <StartDate>2019-02-02</StartDate>
</Worker>
 </Workers>
```

Can someone help me find out what else i can try to get correct sequence number( `<RecordNumber>` please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define a variable to hold the `Days` value, and add that on to the `dayNo` parameter when you replicate the `Units`

```
<xsl:variable name="days" select="Days" />
<xsl:for-each select="1 to Units">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$currElem" mode="replicate">
    <xsl:with-param name="dayNo" select=". + $days"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:for-each>
```